# RFC_READ_TABLE passing "options" and "Fields" parameters (c#)

Tags: c#, abap, sap-dotnet-connector

Need help, I'm trying to get sales data from SAP Using RFC_READ_TABLE, but don't know how to pass OPTIONS and FIELDS parameters to SAP. Here sample code of my app.

Connection is working, after execution, I  have an exception "DATA_BUFFER_EXCEEDED"

```
public void RFC_READ_TABLE()
    {
        try
        {
            ECCDestinationConfig cfg = new ECCDestinationConfig();

            RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);

            RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("ABI_ERP");

            RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;

            IRfcFunction fn = repo.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");

            fn.SetValue("QUERY_TABLE", "VBAP");

            fn.GetTable("DATA");

            fn.Invoke(dest);

            var companyCodeList = fn.GetTable("VBAP");

            var companyDataTable = companyCodeList.ToDataTable("VBAP");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = companyDataTable;
        }
        catch (RfcBaseException x)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Some problems in programe execution. Check entered data, and try again." +
                                        "\n" +
                                        "\n<SAP Remote Execution Error>" +
                                        "\n" +
                                        "\nAdditional Information on Error: " + x.Message, "Oops, Runtime Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I got DATA\_BUFFER\_EXCEED when calling RFC\_READ\_TABLE to CDPOS in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165551/why-i-got-data-buffer-exceed-when-calling-rfc-read-table-to-cdpos-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

`RFC_READ_TABLE` isn't the ideal function module to be using to read sales order data (it's really designed for quick-n'-dirty table reads where nothing else exists). I'd investigate the following RFC-enabled function modules:

- `BAPI_SALESORDER_GETLIST` - get a list of sales documents
- `BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST` - read the details of a single sales document

If you look at function group `2032` or at *Sales and Distribution* -> *Sales* -> *Sales Order* in transaction `BAPI` you'll find others that may help.

Answer (score 3):

You should only define the columns you really need, like after `SELECT` in SQL, i.e Sales document, item and material number:

```
IRfcTable fieldsTable = fn.GetTable("FIELDS");
fieldsTable.Append();
fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "VBELN"); //Sales Document
fieldsTable.Append();
fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "POSNR"); // Sales Document Item
fieldsTable.Append();
fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "MATNR"); // Material number
```

If you don't do that, the invoke will fail because of Data buffer exceeded, as you mentioned. This is because `DATA` structure in `RFC_READ_TABLE` function is of type `TAB512`, this means that each row can contain only up to 512 characters. The length of the content of all columns combined in the table you query (`VBAP`) is around 1500 characters. [Here you can see the length of each field.](https://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tabl/vbap.html)

Then you also wish to filter table, similarly as `WHERE` clause in SQL.

```
IRfcTable options = fn.GetTable("OPTIONS");
options.Append();
options.SetValue("TEXT", "VBELN = '000000000' AND POSNR = '000000'");
options.Append();
options.SetValue("TEXT", " OR VBELN = '000000001' AND POSNR = '000001'");
```

Here you also need to be careful, because each option text should be max 72 characters long. If you need multiple or longer `WHERE` clauses, just append new option like fileds.
I've noticed, that `OR` causes some performance issues on some tables.

After setting these two properties of your function you should be able to successfully invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Narrow down your query by using the 'options' and 'fields' tables options for RFC_READ_TABLE.