# Direct run of SQL query with PyRFC

Tags: sql, saprfc, function-module, pyrfc

I am new to python. I want to pull data from SAP System. I have created a connection with SAP system using below code and trying to pull data using SQL query:

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table_name where col1= 2019
```

Program:

```
    import pyrfc
    from pyrfc import Connection

    conn = Connection(ashost='myhost', sysnr='00', client='000', user='xxx', passwd='***')

    fields = ['col1','col2','col3']

    table = 'table_name'

    where = ['col1=2019']

    MaxRows =5

    fromrow = 0

    tables = conn.call("RFC_READ_TABLE", QUERY_TABLE=table, FIELDS = fields,OPTIONS=where,ROWCOUNT = MaxRows,ROWSKIPS=fromrow)
```

Is there any direct way to write SQL query (how we write in Oracle/SQL)?

The above code gives data in dict form and runs very slow.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any direct way to write sql query

no. PyRFC is not intended for direct SQL queries, it can only call existing SAP RFC-modules.

What concerns function modules which eats pure SQL look at the function groups `RSDU_SQL_XXX`

[image]

if we speak about Oracle DB then it is `RSDU_EXEC_SQL_ORA` module and generic `RSDU_EXEC_SQL`.

However, they are not RFC so cannot be used with PyRFC without some alteration, so you need an ABAP developer or you are out of the luck.

Comment: thank you ..just need one more info..If I need to select all columns from table , what to mention in Fields variable. If I give blank , it ask for list. Also how to give multiple where condition with AND.

Comment: I want also to run this statement: 

select * from table where col1 = value and col2= value and col3= value
I wrote:

fields = ['']

table = 'table'

where = [ 'col1 = value and col2= value and col3= value']


ABAPApplicationError: RFC_ABAP_EXCEPTION (rc=5): key=FIELD_NOT_VALID, message= Number:000 [MSG: class=, type=, number=000, v1-4:=;;;]

Comment: to the FIELDS you should pass fieldnames, not the empty list. There are number examples of RFC_READ_TABLE on SO, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633332/rfc-read-table-passing-options-and-fields-parametrs-c)