# JCo RFC_READ_TABLE Data Buffer Exceeded

Tags: java, abap, connector, jco

i'm trying to get data from Table VBRK via Function RFC_READ_TABLE but always getting a Data Buffer Exceeded Exception.

```
final JCoConnection managedConnection2 = sapCoreJCoManagedConnectionFactory.getManagedConnection("JCoStateless",
        getClass().getName(), rfcDestination);

final JCoFunction function2 = managedConnection2.getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");

final JCoParameterList importParameterList2 = function2.getImportParameterList();

importParameterList2.setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "VBRK");
final JCoParameterList tableParameterList2 = function2.getTableParameterList();

final JCoTable optionsTable = tableParameterList2.getTable("OPTIONS");
String selectionFilter = "VBELN EQ '" + "0123456789" + "'";
optionsTable.appendRow();
optionsTable.setValue("TEXT", selectionFilter);

//execute function RFC_READ_TABLE
managedConnection2.execute(function2);
```

Can anybody point out my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I got DATA\_BUFFER\_EXCEED when calling RFC\_READ\_TABLE to CDPOS in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165551/why-i-got-data-buffer-exceed-when-calling-rfc-read-table-to-cdpos-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because selected field do not fit into structure DATA i.e TAB512. Further, Function Module **RFC_READ_TABLE** also limits if read exceeds 512 bytes per row of data.

You have applied **OPTIONS** to SELECT records but you did not limit SELECTED fields using **FIELDS**. If you will limit SELECTED fields then you will not face error Data Buffer Exceeded. It is also recommend to limit no of records using **ROWCOUNT**.